# PHP Convert seconds into MM:DD:HH:MM:SS

Tags: php, date, math, format, seconds

I would like some help converting seconds into a **MM:DD:HH:MM:SS** format.

I have this code here:

```
<?php
    // Convert seconds into months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds.
    function secondsToTime($ss) {
    $s = $ss%60;
    $m = floor(($ss%3600)/60);
    $h = floor(($ss%86400)/3600);
    $d = floor(($ss%2592000)/86400);
    $M = floor($ss/2592000);

    return "$M months, $d days, $h hours, $m minutes, $s seconds";
    }
?>
```

It outputs an example of

> 0 months, 1 days, 3 hours, 46 minutes, 39 seconds

I would just like it to be something like

> 00:01:03:46:39

How can I do that?

Comment: use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) instead ?

Comment: what is $ss you are passing in ? integer(timestamp) ?

Comment: Doing as @OneTrickPony suggests or using [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) should make it much easier for you. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: is there a good reason why you are redoing this? @OneTrickPony has a good solution unless you do.

Comment: I'm using an integer pulled from the DB across multiple rows using a while statement. It's for a rankings by play time page.

Comment: Why don't you just removes the `months, days, hours, minutes, seconds` from your code and change them with `:`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I gather, it looks like you're interested in returning a string with values containing two digits separaed by colons. Assuming the positioning doesn't need to change, you can do something similar to the following:

```
<?php
// Prefix single-digit values with a zero.
function ensure2Digit($number) {
    if($number < 10) {
        $number = '0' . $number;
    }
    return $number;
}

// Convert seconds into months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds.
function secondsToTime($ss) {
    $s = ensure2Digit($ss%60);
    $m = ensure2Digit(floor(($ss%3600)/60));
    $h = ensure2Digit(floor(($ss%86400)/3600));
    $d = ensure2Digit(floor(($ss%2592000)/86400));
    $M = ensure2Digit(floor($ss/2592000));

    return "$M:$d:$h:$m:$s";
}
```

Or if you don't like the thought of having one more function to manage, perhaps this may suit you better:

```
<?php
// Convert seconds into months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds.
function secondsToTime($ss) {
    $s = $ss%60;
    $m = floor(($ss%3600)/60);
    $h = floor(($ss%86400)/3600);
    $d = floor(($ss%2592000)/86400);
    $M = floor($ss/2592000);

    // Ensure all values are 2 digits, prepending zero if necessary.
    $s = $s < 10 ? '0' . $s : $s;
    $m = $m < 10 ? '0' . $m : $m;
    $h = $h < 10 ? '0' . $h : $h;
    $d = $d < 10 ? '0' . $d : $d;
    $M = $M < 10 ? '0' . $M : $M;

    return "$M:$d:$h:$m:$s";
}
```

And then to call our function (whichever method you decide to use):

```
<?php

$ss = 123456;
print secondsToTime($ss);

?>
```

Comment: Just an alternative: `substr('0'.$someInteger,-2)` gets you a 2 digit result

Comment: a little hacky, but yes that would also give the desired effect of prefixing with a zero when needed. :)

Comment: Thanks for both of those answers! I never knew you could do it like that. I'll use it for learning purposes (:

Comment: You missed a "(" on your second function. That needs it right, or should the other ) be removed?

Comment: you're right, i had a `)` which shouldn't have been present. fixed.

Comment: How can the result be echo'ed?

Comment: @OleSørensen: `<?php print secondsToTime(123456);?>`

Answer (score 2):

The easy way:

```
print date('m:d:h:i:s', $ss); // $ss = seconds
```

This however can't handle years the way you want it as far as I know, because it will start counting from 1970. But apparently you don't need to display years.

Alternatively, you could just format your current string with [`(s)printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
printf('%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d', $M, $d, $h, $m, $s);
```

Comment: I'm using a while statement to get the seconds from multiple rows. Printf and print both set the result at the top of my table for some reason.

Comment: That's because `printf` prints the string when its called. Use `sprintf` if you want to return it in your function, and print it later

Comment: I tried sprintf as you said, but the fetched data wouldn't even show up.

Comment: You needed to replace the `return` line from your function with `return sprintf ...`

Answer (score 0):

Given all your variables, you can simply build the string with PHP:

`$str = "$M:$d:$h:$m:$s"`

This code wont handle the leading zero's however.

Comment: No offense, but I knew this. I wanted the leading zeros though.